# Hallwachs' Experiment: why zinc?

Tags: experimental-physics, photoelectric-effect

The famous experiment by Hallwachs that eventually lead to Einstein's photon hypothesis was conducted using a negatively charged *zinc* plate. I always thought that the effect was initially observed with a zinc plate because of its low work function, but just now I found out that there are [many other metals with lower work functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function#Work_functions_of_elements[11]).

Why is zinc always used in demonstration experiments?

Comment: Sure, but how many of them are cheap, easy to clean, and readily available?

Comment: [Easily oxidising atoms and ones with a low work function are correlated](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/239491/85443). I guess it would be more difficult to manufacture the tube without the surfaces becoming oxidised.